# Android AlarmManager not working when set for longer time

Tags: android, android-alarms

In my app I have tried to set an alarm using this code:

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);

        Intent intent = new Intent(G.context, AlarmService.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext, 1010, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        G.alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

It works when I set the alarm for 1 minute or later, but not when I set the alarm for 30 or 40 minutes later. While I am not on the phone for 30 minutes, after 30 minutes the alarm did not work, and when the phone screen is on the alarm worked...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi mosheni, welcome to StackOverflow, please read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since API 19 `set()` is treated as inexact and may be delayed. If you really need a precise alarm, you should use [setExact()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) (available since API 19) instead :

> Note: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is
>   treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time,
>   but may be deferred and delivered some time later. The OS will use
>   this policy in order to "batch" alarms together across the entire
>   system, minimizing the number of times the device needs to "wake up"
>   and minimizing battery use. In general, alarms scheduled in the near
>   future will not be deferred as long as alarms scheduled far in the
>   future.

This change happen on 19+ device (obviously) but also only if the APK's **target** API is 19+, so you can

- change the target API to 18
- or use [Build.VERSION.SDK_INT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) to know which method to use.

Additionnaly when you use a `*_WAKE_UP` alarm, the alarm manager garantees that the device will be awake long enough to execute the receiver's method, but not the service it may launch :

> The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm
>   receiver's onReceive() method is executing. This guarantees that the
>   phone will not sleep until you have finished handling the broadcast.
>   Once onReceive() returns, the Alarm Manager releases this wake lock.
>   This means that the phone will in some cases sleep as soon as your
>   onReceive() method completes. If your alarm receiver called
>   Context.startService(), it is possible that the phone will sleep
>   before the requested service is launched.

The support v4 library provides a usefull helper class to handle this case : [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html)

In you case, as you are using a service pending intent, I am not sure what wake garanties apply.

Comment: my min API is 11 .. What to do ؟

Comment: I would first change the *target*  API to see if the behaviour is different.

Comment: As of API level 26.0.0 WakefulBroadcastReceiver is deprercated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok that's because after a long time (let's say more than 5 min) your app is Paused and then the phone is "asleep" with lock screen. When you unlock it then you get your Alarm because it was queued.
To solve this problem, you need to implement a Wake Lock and add it's permission to your manifest file.
According to Google Documentation "A wake lock is a mechanism to indicate that your application needs to have the device stay on."
This is the line you have to add in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

You'll need to implement this object in your onReceive() method in your BroadcastReceiver. You can follow this tutorial that makes use of all you need.
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-alarmmanager-tutorial.html

Also, note that you'll keep the device "awake" therefore you'll keep the phone processing affecting the battery life, but still you get to be able to get the alarm even if the screen is locked.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

i use service

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    //This is my Code and set Alarm
    stopSelf();
}
```

}